# excel validation custom function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my first post so hopefully it will be within regulations etc.

I am trying to write a data validation using the custom option.

The validation needs to check a date against potentially 3 other dates.  I say potentially as one might not be filled in.

The the first two are boundary dates CalSD and CalED (Calendar Start Date and Calendar End Date)

The check dates are start and finish dates within a scope.

The ScopeStart Date needs to be:
less than ScopeEnd Date
less than CalED
greater than or equal to CalSD
both a number and a date

i have tried using:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(D13),OR(D13<E13,NOT(ISNUMBER(E13))),D13>=CalSD,D13<CalED,LEFT(CELL("format",D13),1)="D")
```

However it appears to not like the OR section.  if the date in E13 is missing then D13 is not < E13 and so the validation no longer works if the date d13>CalED for instance.

when there are two dates the validation works fine, or if I remove that section it works fine.  but then there is nothing to check that the start is before the end scope date.

Hope all that makes sense?

Cheers

JontyR

Comment: Fixed, just a formatting issue

Comment: So you need another check that D13/E13 (?) isn't blank? Are these cells scopestart and scopeend?

Comment: Is ScopeStart Date = D13 & ScopeEnd Date = E13 ?

Comment: Firstly thank you for the responses, I am grateful that people took the time to look at my problem!

Mako212 - I am struggling to see what you edited to make the formatting change?  I have copied the formula out and it looks identical to the one I entered...confused!  lol

SJR and phidot - yes D13 and E13 are the scope start and end dates respectively.  There are around 130 combinations of these across the sheet which is why I am keen to do it via a data validation.